# Google Drive: Open share dialog

Tags: client, google-drive-api

I want to open a share dialog (pick user's to share with and so on, standard Drive share dialog) in my desktop app. I have a browser integrated in my app, all I need is point out a URL to open the dialog. How can I get it? Can find in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [share dialog documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing#launching_the_google_drive_sharing_dialog_in_your_app) for you.

Comment: I mentioned in my question, for this I need a page and it works for web apps where you have pages. I don't - I can open browser with some page. And generation of it locally sounds crazy.